# Separate thread with infinite loop blocking gui update Netbeans

Tags: java, multithreading, netbeans

This would be my first program using threads so would appreciate any help i can get. Created a new Netbeans Java Desktop App and would like to know where at what point in the automatically generated code can I instantiate and run my runnable interface class so that it would not block the gui part of the application (event dispatcher thread i think).

This runnable thread of mine would contain an infinite loop listening for incoming UDP packets.

Thank you for all the help !
ankit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it an asynchronous thread and call it whenever you want it to start running.

Comment: not sure how would i do that ... when i call <my runnable class>.run() from my event dispatcher thread, how do i make it async ? would appreciate if you could provide a code sample or a link. thanks :)

Comment: nvm .. works perfectly now .. thank you for pointing in the right direction :D !

Comment: You're welcome, sounds like you just needed a little encouragement.